# Latest Visual Studio Community 2017 Installer on Windows 10 - Bluescreen

Tags: windows-10, macbook-pro-retina, visual-studio-2017

So I was installing Visual Studio 2017 Community today, and I started the installation and got away. When I got back, I was presented with a Recovery Screen, telling me that Windows might not be installed properly. **There shouldn’t be any viruses on my computer. It’s a fresh installation of Windows 10 Pro (1803 ?), and the installation ISO was downloaded directly from Microsoft. The only software installed on it is the Bootcamp Helper since I’m using a Macbook.** I *thought* it had nothing to do with Visual Studio, so I booted from my installation USB, mounted EFI partition with `diskpart`, created boot files with `bcdboot` and one reboot later, it was all fine. Until the Visual Studio Installer automatically restarted and attempted to continue installing, but it crashed the computer. It gave the error `KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE`. I thought there was something wrong at the Microsoft’s side, so I force restarted the computer a bunch of times to get to Recovery Options, and I booted with the option “Disable Driver Signing Enforcement” and it didn’t blue screen this time. Everything seems fine so far. Should I worry about it? What can be the cause of this? Is there any known issue with the installer (I searched it on google already and found nothing)? **I downloaded Visual Studio Installer directly from Microsoft as well.**

**My computer:** Macbook Pro Early-2015 13" Model, 8 GB RAM, Intel Core i5

**EDIT:** As requested, here are the things I attempted to install:

> Universal Windows Platform Development
>
> .NET Desktop Development
>
> C++ Desktop Development
>
> ASP.NET
>
> Python
>
> C++ Linux Development
>
> .NET Core

And an extra package:

> C++ ARM and ARM64 compilers and libraries

Comment: Which update are you installing 16.7 (update 7) or a previous version?

Comment: Just went to the computer to check it and appearently it crashed again with the same error. I think the disabling driver signing enforcement didn’t help at all.

Comment: By the way, it should be the latest version, I just downloaded it. And a few blue screens later, I have a 0xc000001 (Your PC couldn’t turn off properly) screen. I have the option to continue booting. What should I do?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what your installing?  There are dozens of components to VS2017

Comment: A few retries later, I could install it with no problems, but my question not how to fix this. It is “should I worry about it?”.

Comment: Appearently the BSODs have nothing to do with Visual Studio, but Windows 10 is broken. I will downgrade to Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 (17xx).

Comment: In order to figure out the reason, you were encountering a BSOD, you would have to use windbg and analyze your mini dumps.  We can help you with that process, if you provided the required information, in order to do that.  It's possible the problem is a conflict with 1803 and the Bootcamp drivers.  Has Apple released drivers that indicate specific support for 1803?

Comment: It has drivers for Windows 10 but not sure if it supports 1803.

Comment: analyze the [crash dump files wit Windbg to see the cause](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)